# /bin/sh: mpic++ command not found in Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers

Tags: eclipse, macos, mpi, sh

I'm trying to use Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers to do some MPI stuff but I can't get the program to compile.  Below is the error I'm getting in the console:

```
Description Resource    Path        Location        Type
/bin/sh: mpic++: command not found  prog            C/C++ Problem
```

I use `mpic++` from the command line (bash shell) to successfully compile programs.  When I run the command using bourne shell I get an error.

```
/bin/sh mpic++
/usr/local/bin/mpic++: /usr/local/bin/mpic++: cannot execute binary file
```

When I use `sudo` I still get the same error.  But when I first change to the bourne shell then run the mpic++ command it works.

```
/bin/sh
sh-3.2$ mpic++
clang: error: no input files
```

I've been looking at ways to change the shell used by eclipse so I can use the bash shell because I can call `mpic++` without any problems.  I've also tried launching eclipse with `sudo` but that didn't work.

Comment: Your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` / `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables are not set properly. Check your shell initialisation scripts (`~/.something_profile` and `~/.somethingrc`).

Comment: Do you mean the initialisation script for the bourne shell?  I installed openmpi using brew in the bash shell.  I couldn't find those environment variables in either the bash or the bourne shell.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled mpi in eclipse successfully. Please follow the steps:

1. In terminal type:

> $ which mpicxx
>
> `/usr/local/bin/mpicxx`

You should get the `mpicxx` binary path as result. I have my mpicxx in `/usr/local/bin/` directory.

2. In eclipse, go to project properties:

   - Set GCC C Compiler as: `/usr/local/bin/mpicxx`
   - Also set GCC C+ Compiler as: `/usr/local/bin/mpicxx`
   - Set MacOS X C++ Linker as: `/usr/local/bin/mpicxx`. Also set All options as `-L/usr/local/lib`

[image: GCC C++ Compiler]
[image: MacOS X C++ Linker]